# Caching JTable rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Is it possible to cache all row renderers so that each row is rendered just once after table updates? I am not expecting much data.

Comment: the answer is no (as you already learned in your last question :) Still waiting for code ...

Comment: See also this [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12153452/230513).

Comment: So I can't increase default cache to span more rows?

Comment: last reminder (after that, you'll be on your own, at least as far as I'm concerned): from your description, I don't understand what you are _really_ after (which might well be a language issue) - Do.Show.An.SSCCE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JTable` [renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) serve the view; an RTL renderer should have no perceptible overhead unless your model's `getValueAt()` implementation imposes it. Instead, let your `TableModel` acquire its data, [caching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/221525/230513) only if necessary. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513) `extends AbstractTableModel` and acquires its entire data on construction. If acquisition will impose a delay, use an instance of [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), as shown in the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) or in this [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/randomdata).

Comment: +1 inspite of torpeding my efforts to wring out some code :-)

Comment: Guilty as charged! I was hoping that @Ahmet might add an RTL renderer to my [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513) as a test.

Comment: thanks, gonna need some time to digest this info and how it relates to my situation though. I guess the problem is related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333577/string-width-via-fontmetrics-calculation-is-very-slow-if-there-are-arabic-or-per

Comment: This may be (at least partially) platform dependent. If the delay is perceptible, let the model cache each row's completed `TextLayout` where the renderer can access it quickly.

Comment: Yes, the delay is indeed perceptiple. Your suggestion looks promising, but I have two questions; 1) How do I acquire the automatically calculated TextLayout? Do you mean I should calculate it myself? 2) How do I make the renderer use the previously calculated TextLayout?

Comment: You might looks the examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5998117/230513), showing how to construct the `TextLayout`, and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4287269/230513), showing how to buffer an image of the rendered text. You'll have to profile to see which would be better.

Comment: As in your second example, I used BufferedImage by overriding paintingComponent (instead of setText method) and it is now ultra fast. Do you know how I could multi-line the output? I am using a JTextArea instead of a JLabel in my renderer, which auto-adjusts row sizes according to text lengths. But since now I am using an image instead everything is on one line.

Comment: Excellent. You can `paint()` any component in a `BufferedImage`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7028497/230513).

Comment: I guess you meant painting JTextArea and caching the BufferedImage to be later returned by getTableCellRendererComponent. So I removed my paintComponent override and tried that. The result: Creating TextLayout dynamically and painting it was lot faster than using setText on JTextArea and caching it. Besides that, caching significiantly increased ram usage. So I guess I will stick with the first technique. But on the other hand, I need to split my string into several lines. The following may solve my problem: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/WrapstringaccordingtoFontMetrics.htm